# HTML JS assembling array name works fine but then prints as a "string" rather than the actual job

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am doing a bit of prelim coding for a game with robots.

I have written a short program in JavaScript to track turns and player in the game.
I can update the turns, return whose turn it is no problem.

I want to use arrays to hold info about players. I'm learning at the moment so for now I'm using an array with only 2 elements.

The names are `player1_data`, `player2_data`, etc. I want to find out the content of array element 0, so it becomes player1_data[0], which is fine.

If I type this in all is fine and I get my element returned to me.

However, if I assemble the array info, by going "player" + current_player + "_data[" + element +"]" then it looks fine, but simply doesn't not function.

It just a string of characters, not the actual array element request that I get if I type it in manually!

What is the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="button" onclick="vardisplay(), updateturn() ">SHOW VARIABLES</button>


    <p id="para1">false</p>
    <p id="para2">2</p>
    <p id="para3">2</p>
    <p id="para4">2</p>
    <p id="para5">2</p>
    <p id="para6">2</p>
    <p id="para7">2</p>
    <p id="para8">2</p>

    <script>

      var ifselect = 0
      var current_turn = 0
      var last_turn = 0
      var players_in_game = 5
      var current_player = 1

      var current_robot = 123
      var player_id = "player" + current_player + "_data";

      var arrayselector = 0
      var player_array_display = player_id + "[" + arrayselector + "]";

      var player1_data = ["dave", current_robot];
      var player2_data = ["kim", current_robot];
      var player3_data = ["nigel", current_robot];
      var player4_data = ["bob", current_robot];

      function updateturn() {

        if (current_player > players_in_game - 1) {
          current_player = 1
          current_turn = current_turn + 1

        } else {
          current_player = current_player + 1;
          player_id = "player" + current_player + "_data";
          player_array_display = player_id + "[" + arrayselector + "]";
        }
      }

      function vardisplay() {

        document.getElementById("para1").innerHTML = "random stuff";
        document.getElementById("para2").innerHTML = "players_in_game:     " + players_in_game;
        document.getElementById("para3").innerHTML = "current_turn:     " + current_turn;
        document.getElementById("para4").innerHTML = "current_player:  " + current_player;
        document.getElementById("para5").innerHTML = "current_robot:     " + current_robot;
        document.getElementById("para6").innerHTML = "player_id:    " + player_id;
        document.getElementById("para7").innerHTML = "player_array_display:     " + player_array_display;
        document.getElementById("para8").innerHTML = player2_data[0];

      }


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I should say that paragraph "para8" just shows that the thing works.

Comment: `para8` shows the value of `kim`, which is correct. `para7` the value you have assigned in this line: `player_array_display= player_id +"["+ arrayselector +"]".

Answer (score 2):

> I want to use arrays to hold info about players. Im learning at the moment so for now I'm using an array with only 2 elements. The names are player1_data, player2_data etc.

Don't do this.  Instead of grouping **similarly named variables** whose relationship is based on naming conventions, group **values** using the collections provided by the language.

```
var player_data_for_all_players = [player1_data, player2_data];
```

will allow you to do

```
player_data_for_all_players[player_index][array_selector]
```

or

```
var player_data_by_name = {
  'dave': current_robot,
  ...
};
```

which allows you to identify players using a (unique) value that is more self-explanatory in a debugging console.

Answer (score 0):

You need an array of array. Like this :

```
var players_data = [];
players_data[1] = ["dave",current_robot];
players_data[2] = ["kim",current_robot];
players_data[3] = ["nigel",current_robot];
players_data[4] = ["bob",current_robot];
```

Now if you want to display the information for the second player, you just have to do this :

```
var name = players_data[2][0]
```

But it should be better to use an array of object to have a more "readable" code :

```
var players_data = [];
players_data[1] = {
    name : 'dave',
    robot : current_robot
};

// Access to the name of the first player
var name = players_data[1].name
```

Comment: Aha! Fantastic, thanks for the help. Im teaching myself at home, and while it is pretty straight forwards, its tricky and knotty in places.

Comment: I am still having problems getting the data back out. the above line where it says

    players_data[1] = {

HOw do I insert a variable where the [1] is so I can get 

      players_data[current number player] .name

Comment: Just replace `1` by your variable : `players_data[current_number].name`